# Saving/inserting multiple records with Python Twistar

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted

Extending the Twistar [example code](https://github.com/bmuller/twistar#usage), I'm trying to write multiple records at once:

```
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi
from twistar.registry import Registry
from twistar.dbobject import DBObject
from twisted.internet import reactor

class User(DBObject):
     pass

def done(user):
     print "A user was just created with the name %s" % user.first_name
     #The example calls reactor.stop() here

Registry.DBPOOL = adbapi.ConnectionPool('MySQLdb', user="twistar", passwd="apass", db="twistar")

# I've added this function:
def write_user(first_name)
     u = User(first_name=first_name)
     u.save().addCallback(done)

new_users = ["Alice","Bob"]

for new_user in new_users:
     #Here's where I call the function repeatedly:
     write_user(new_user)

reactor.run()
```

As it is, this example prints:

```
A user was just created with the name Alice
A user was just created with the name Bob
```

But the program never exits! Adding `reactor.stop()` to the `done()` function causes the script to exit after printing just

```
A user was just created with the name Alice
```

So that's clearly not right, but both records are added to the database, anyway.

How should I be doing this?

Comment: I ended up using another Python ORM called [peewee](https://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). I wrapped my for loop in a transaction, so all the rows are transmitted at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to return the defer of `u.save()` like that:

```
 def write_user(first_name)
      u = User(first_name=first_name)
      return u.save()
```

Then, in your loop when you `write_user`, you need to store those Deferred:

```
 results = []
 for new_user in new_users:
     results.append(write_user(new_user))
 # Here, all deferred except the last one will call done.
 DeferredList(results[:-1]).addCallback(done)
 # Here, the last Deferred will call reactor.stop after he's done.
 results[-1].addCallback(done).addCallback(reactor.stop)
```

With this, you can close the reactor only when the last user has been saved.